# Tutorial for doing a pull-down "view" in android?

Tags: android, menu, view, pull

This is a UI element that I have seen a lot lately (in the NY Times app and Grooveshark App) and I want to learn how to implement it but I can't find a guide. Does anyone know of a tutorial or guide for implementing such a thing or are these custom implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that there is a UI element in android called SlidingDrawer that does just this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: Info : Deprecated with API 17 +

Answer (score 1):

if you lack the possibility to make a slidingdrawer that can go from top to bottem or left to right i can recommand http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/. Get the sourcecode with samples. Might maybe be what you are looking for. (Though it is only down->up afaik)