# Resize height of ImageView by finger

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I have an activity that shows the camera preview, and an ImageView of the last image taken.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stitch_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stitch_preview"/>
```

Right now the ImageView is fixed to `128dp` height. Is difficult to make this view resizable by dragging your finger down on the ImageView.

I've been searching for various hints, but everything I find relates to pulling out a hidden view. I can't seem to find an example of resizing an already visible view.

[Tutorial for doing a pull-down "view" in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212693/tutorial-for-doing-a-pull-down-view-in-android)

[How to resize a custom view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963152/android-how-to-resize-a-custom-view-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

By assuming that your ImageView is visible,Following steps may help you-

1)Pinch-zoom your ImageView  or actually resize your imageview using LayoutParams using multitouch(You can resize Imageview as per your standard bound).

2)Take capture of your imageview using following code

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewbyId(R.id.ImageView1)
```

....

```
iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                // Set the layout manually to after resizing or pinch zoom
                iv.layout(0, 0, x, y);
                // Set the quality to high
                iv.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
                // Build the cache, get the bitmap and close the cache
                iv.buildDrawingCache(true);
                Bitmap bmBarChart = gv.toBitmap();
```

the above code will return you the re-sized bitmap image.

3)Now save this image and set it to your ImageView

i have already resized the visible view before but i had slightly different requirement than you